# Problems executing SQL Server Stored Procedures from EFCore

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a database with several tables, and I have prepared a stored procedure (basically consisting of delete * from ... statements) to delete rows from these tables. When I run the stored procedure from SQL Server Management Studio, it works just fine.
Now, I'd like to execute the same stored procedure from my C# application. I use the below code to do this:

```
using (var context = new DBContext())
{
    var param = new SqlParameter[] {...}; //create parameters here
    //trigger the stored procedure for deletion from the first table here
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("[dbo].[delete_first] @id,@date", param);
                        
    //trigger the stored procedure for deletion from the hts_clients table here
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("[dbo].[delete_second] @id,@date", param);
}
```

When executed, the first invocation seems to work fine. However, the second one always throws an exception with the following message:

> Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1. Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1

(Note: Yes, the exception message appears exactly like this. I didn't paste it twice.)

However, I'm definitely not using any transactions in the bodies of the stored procedures i.e I have no Begin Transaction/Commit Transaction/Rollback Transactions statements anywhere in either of them, nor did I wrap the invocation in a transaction from EFCore (as can be seen from the code segment above). Can anyone tell me why this is happening?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most ORM's and EF among them do use transactions internally. Sadly I got no clue about the error.

Comment: Maybe use different set of parameters on second invocation?

Comment: Have you tried to manually exec your sp with the same parameters?
It's probably throwing errors. Does your sp have try/catch blocks?

Comment: Are there any triggers on tables? Maybe try only executing the first from app and have the first proc exec the second...?

Comment: Must be something in the sprocs. EF doesn't even start a transaction here.

Answer (score 0):

The dbContext is not getting refreshed automatically after executeSql. You have to reload the entry that was changed.

try to use this:

```
 context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("[dbo].[delete_first] @id,@date", param);
  _context.Entry(...deletionClass...  ).Reload();
 
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("[dbo].[delete_second] @id,@date", param);

//and maybe if you need  you can try it again
 _context.Entry(...deletionClass...  ).Reload();
```

but in your case maybe easier to create a new DbContext  for the second stored procedure.

```
using (var context1 = new DBContext())
{
    var param = new SqlParameter[] {...}; //create parameters here
    //trigger the stored procedure for deletion from the first table here
    context1.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("[dbo].[delete_first] @id,@date", param);
 }
 using (var context2 = new DBContext())
{
var param = new SqlParameter[] {...}; //create parameters here                      
    //trigger the stored procedure for deletion from the hts_clients table here
    context2.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("[dbo].[delete_second] @id,@date", param);
}
```